# Импорт ключа реестра из кода

Tags: c#, реестр

Хочу текст файлов реестра перенести в код в переменные string . Импортировать уже из переменных.

Так нормально импортируется

```
var text= @"d:\_images\1.reg";
```

Из текста не импортируется

```
var text = @"
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
""MenuShowDelay"" = ""1"" 
";

Console.WriteLine(text);
Process MyProc = new Process();
MyProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"reg";
MyProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "import" + " " + text;
MyProc.Start();
```

Comment: А почему должно? Аргументом у reg import служит имя файла, а не строка а содержимым.

Comment: Можно как-то конвертировать?

Comment: Строку с текстом в имя файла? Да, запишите текст в файл и скормите его имя.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем обязательно внешние утилиты?

```
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop"))
    key.SetValue("MenuShowDelay", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Comment: Чтобы было проще редактировать ключи.

Comment: подробные примеры https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5